# for Imbalanced data dealing with cat boost

Tags: python-3.x, catboost

Is there a parameter like "scale_pos_weight" in catboost package as we used to have in the xgboost package in python ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the parameter is named "class_weights", you can find it here : [Documentation](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/python-reference_parameters-list-docpage/#python-reference_parameters-list)

You have to pass a list like [0.8, 0.2] for binary or [0.3, 0.8, 0.4, 0.6] for multiclass of 4 for example. Doesn't have to sum to 1, it's used as a multiplier.

Answer (score 8):

CatBoost also has scale_pos_weight parameter starting from version 0.6.1

Comment: Can you provide some more information (ex a link or an example?)

Comment: @Kosnik You can check here https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/python-reference_catboostclassifier-docpage/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use "auto_class_weights" and "scale_pos_weight" as described in original catboost documentations: https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_parameters-list.html